# Reference local code in SAM using CfnFunction in the CDK with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I'm using the AWS CDK to create a SAM [CfnFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sam.CfnFunction.html).

For the `codeUri` property, it needs to reference a [`S3LocationProperty`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sam.CfnFunction.S3LocationProperty.html).

When using the SAM CLI, I can do something like this

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
```

Where `hello_world` has the code for my function.

Running `sam build` and `sam deploy` does the work of packaging and uploading the code to S3, and deploying a Cloudformation Template with the proper `CodeUri` path in S3.

I try and do something similar using the CDK (Python) but the work behind the scenes done by the SAM cli doesn't happen

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_sam as sam
)

class SamStack(core.Stack):
    
    def __init__(self, id, scope: core.Construct, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(id, scope, **kwargs)

        sam_stack = sam.CfnFunction(
            self, "MySamFunction",
            code_uri="lambda",  # Directory with my code
            runtime="python3.8",
            handler="MyFunction.handler",
            # other properties removed
        )
```

Running `cdk deploy` errors on stack creation with

```
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [InferenceSam] is invalid. 'CodeUri' is not a valid S3 Uri of the form 's3://bucket/key' with optional versionId query parameter.
```

Is there a way do automate the packaging and uploading of my python code to S3 using the CDK?

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing, following is the method I used

```
cdk-project
 | package.json
 | cdk.json
 | stack.ts
 |- lambda (sam application directory)
    | template.yaml
    |- solution
       | requirements.txt
       |- app       
          | index.py
```

Inside the template.yaml

```
Resources:
  SolutionAPIFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: solution/
      Handler: app.index.lambda_handler
```

Inside the package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "cd lambda && sam build && cd .. && tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
```

so when run "npm run build", it will run the sam build, and it will create a folder under cdk-project/lambda/.aws-sam

Inside the stack.ts

```js
    const aFunction = new Function(this, "aFunction", {
      runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
      handler: "app.index.lambda_handler",
      code: Code.asset('./lambda/.aws-sam/build/SolutionAPIFunction')
      timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(3),
      logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.THREE_MONTHS      
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old but I ran into this issue and it was puzzling so I wanted to share my solution. I was able to solve this issue for my deployment by using the `aws_s3_assets` lib and pass a `local` flag into the serverless stack to decide whether or not to upload the asset on a synth, or use the path for local exec.

e.g.:

```
import aws_cdk.core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_sam as sam
from aws_cdk import aws_s3_assets as s3_assets


class ServerlessStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(
        self, scope: cdk.Construct, id: str, local: bool = False, **kwargs
    ) -> None:

    # function_kwargs is a dict containing specific function params
    # see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_sam/CfnFunction.html

    if not local:
        function_kwargs['code_uri'] = s3_assets.Asset(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{function}asset",
            path=function_kwargs.pop('code_uri')
        ).s3_object_url

    # Create the function resource
    sam.CfnFunction(
        scope=self,
        id=function,
        runtime="python3.8",
        **function_kwargs
    )
```